# Change Styles to FluentUI Progress Component in Blazor

Tags: c#, css, blazor, fluent-ui

I am trying to remove the track from the FluentUI Progress bar. I am only able to use this library so requesting an alternate is not an option.

I have attempted to add css to my application to overwrite, but I believe that any changes I make to the component are overwritten in lieu of the line inside my _Layout.cshtml

```
<script type="module" src="~/css/fluentui/web-components.min.js"></script>
```

**How can I edit the following css within a component I want to use?**

[image: The child element within the progress bar that I want to edit css for]

[image: The child element class with style that I want to change]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you must use design tokens to alter css for FluentUI components. I saw that the component uses a variable in css called --neutral-stroke-strong-rest and was able to look at the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fluent-ui/web-components/integrations/blazor#option-1-using-design-tokens-from-c-code).

In order to get this to work you must perform all the setup from the docs, then in your razor page add your component with a reference for the .cs code

```
<FluentProgress @ref="ref1"></FluentProgress>
```

Then in the .cs code I needed to add:

```
[Inject]
private NeutralStrokeStrongRest neutralStrokeStrongRest { get; set; } = default!;

private FluentProgress? ref1;
```

Then I needed to add the following function to change the actual CSS variables using JS (read more docs for info on this)

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await neutralStrokeStrongRest.SetValueFor(ref1.Element, "#FFFFFF".ToSwatch());

        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

And BOOM, no more track on my progress bar!